# How can I access the menu ID of an element in a Wordpress Nav_Walker

Tags: menus

Using this code as an example (from another post):

```
class Primary_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( array_search( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='dropdown %s'><a href='%s' class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" >%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) || array_search( 'current-page-parent', $item->classes ) ) ? 'active' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        } else {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li %s><a href='%s'>%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? ' class="active"' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        }
    }

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

If the menu `id`, as rendered in the HTML of this menu, is `foobar-nav` I would like to be able to access this value when rendering the `<li>` to create something along the lines of `<li class="menu-foobar-nav-menu-item">`.

I've taken a long look at the `$item` variable to see what it contains but the only thing that caught my eye was `$item->menu_item_parent` which in this case is set to `0` and of no use.

I've also taken a look at the other functions I am able to over-ride to see if I can access the menu id at some earlier point and set it's value to a class property that I can access when rendering the elements, but I can't find anything interesting there.

E.g final output might be something like so:

```
<ul id="foobar-nav">
  <li class="menu-foobar-nav-menu-item">Some menu item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the ID to `wp_nav_menu()` like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_id' => 'foobar-nav',
) );
```

Then you can access it through the `$args` parameter:

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $menu_id = $args['menu_id'];
}
```